# How to use setTimeout with every item in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

In the following:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(cards, function (card) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            observableData().saveCard(card);
        }, 1000);
    });
```

This is supposed to be waiting one second for every card in the array, but it just waits one second and then blasts through the array.  How can I achieve the expected behavior?

Comment: It is waiting one second for each item in the array.  You've just started timers for every item at the same time.  Set a timer for the next item once the first one has occurred.  Or, set an interval and loop through on each callback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to increment the timeouts

```
var idx = 1;
ko.utils.arrayForEach(cards, function (card) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        observableData().saveCard(card);
    }, (idx++) * 1000);
});
```

Since the `arrayForEach` doesn't look like giving the index of the item, you need to maintain a separate index

Answer (score 1):

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(cards, function (card) {
     var timeout =   setTimeout(function () {
            observableData().saveCard(card);
        }, 1000);
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    });
```

Comment: Are you guys triplets or something

Comment: hehe i just noticed it now ...thats just coincidence

Comment: @kadumel i don't know how it happened but i think most of the people with name ARUN are programmers

Comment: @kadumel..ohh y its impossible...?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var timer;
ko.utils.arrayForEach(cards, function (card) 
{
      window.clearTimeout(timer);
        timer=window.setTimeout(function () {
            observableData().saveCard(card);
        }, 1000);
    });
```